# how OpenAI Playground keep track of long conversations?

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I'm testing OpenAI Playground (their web console) and also testing the REST API.

the REST API documentation suggests that I must add all previous iterations to each API call, so I can carry the context information. but there is a token limit.

then, some suggest to summarize the previous iterations, but this will reach the limit eventually too.

when I use the web playground, I can have a very long conversation, and ask for information of the previous iterations, and I get a correct answer.

so my question is: how can I carry the context of a long conversation when using the REST API?

I've seen some articles talking about using a vector database along with the LLM, but as far as I understood, it is not the same thing: in this case I'm supposed to use the LLM to store information in my vector database (by using the embedding information, yada yada) and later querying the database for similar information. but this is not what I want here.

I'm looking for a way to "pre-load" contextual information to a conversation, and then ask questions about this information.

this seems to be possible in the web playground. what kind of mechanism it might use?

Comment: user session and app context these are the two concept that you can use for storing and retrieving the context..